# I have denormal array (different key) list object. I need get per key with index with typescript but this code don't work for me

Tags: typescript

I have denormal array (different key) list object. I need get per key with index, with **typescript** but this code don't work for me.

```
const sell = [{ 'Quantity_1': 0, 'Price_1': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_1': 0 },
    { 'Quantity_2': 0, 'Price_2': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_2': 546,  },
    { 'Quantity_3': 0, 'Price_3': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_3': 546,  },
    { 'Quantity_4': 0, 'Price_4': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_4': 546, },
    { 'Quantity_5': 0, 'Price_5': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_5': 546,  },
    { 'Quantity_6': 0, 'Price_6': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_6': 546,  },
```

```
  for (let i = 0; i < sell.length; i++) {
       result = buy[i]['Quantity_'+i]
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Defined and looped array with name `sell` but accessing `buy` within loop.

Also, array object key names starts with _1 but looped `i` value start from 0 i.e., Quantity_0 does not exists.

Try this:

```
const sell = [{ 'Quantity_1': 0, 'Price_1': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_1': 0 },
    { 'Quantity_2': 0, 'Price_2': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_2': 546,  },
    { 'Quantity_3': 0, 'Price_3': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_3': 546,  },
    { 'Quantity_4': 0, 'Price_4': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_4': 546, },
    { 'Quantity_5': 0, 'Price_5': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_5': 546,  },
    { 'Quantity_6': 0, 'Price_6': 0, 'NumberOfOrders_6': 546,  }];

for (let i = 0; i < sell.length; i++) {
    result = sell[i]["Quantity_" + (i+1)];
}
```